# How to fix web.config redirect that doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to get a redirect working with a web.config file.  The httpRedirect rule  works fine but the rewrite rule doesn't.  I get a 500 error.  If I go to the IIS HTTP Redirect section I get what you see in the following image.  If I remove the rewrite node, it opens fine in the IIS HTTP Redirect window.  What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rewrite_client_contract" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^client/contractreview/index/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://adumbsite.com/contractreview/index/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
            <add wildcard="/public/signup" destination="https://adumbsite.com/sign-up/" />
        </httpRedirect>
    </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is the IIS rewrite module installed on the server?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm an idiot.  I didn't realize that was a separate installation.  Installed that and it's all good now.  Thanks.